# SDL_SetWindowSize resizes window, but SDL_GetWindowSize reports old size -- in Unix

Tags: c++, linux, x11, sdl-2

I can't use `SDL_GetWindowSize` cross-platform, because in Unix it doesn't know that the window size changed (though I can see it did). Visual Studio and MinGW have no problem. (I keep running into cases where Unix is an outlier, but it's always been that I was doing something wrong and the other 2 platforms didn't notice.)

I was running SDL2's version 2.0.8+dfsg1-4ubuntu on 64-bit Ubuntu 4.18.0 on VirtualBox; have since upgraded to SDL2 2.0.9+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 5.0.0, but behavior is the same. It's using GNOME Shell with X11.

The interaction with `SDL_PollEvent` is strange. But I do think it's possible and reasonable to call it sometimes!

So how can I get `SDL_GetWindowSize` to accurately report the size?

MCVE:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    //set things up
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) return -1;

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("",0, 0,640, 480,0);      
    if (!window) return -1;

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    if (!renderer) return -1;

    //I need to be able to resize at times, so this is in the MCVE
    SDL_SetWindowSize(window, 600, 100);

    //Without this line, no problem
    SDL_PollEvent(nullptr); 

    //Assertions fail -- in Unix, not Visual Studio
    int w, h; SDL_GetWindowSize (window, &w, &h);
    assert (w == 600);
    assert (h == 100);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: trying a new test at commenter's suggestion. It does resolve the problem with `SDL_GetWindowSize` reporting the wrong dimensions.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

static void flush_event_queue(void) {
    SDL_Event ev;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev)) {
        printf("ev.type=%d\n", ev.type);
        if(ev.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT) {
            printf("window event %d\n", ev.window.event);
            if(ev.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED || ev.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED) {
                printf("resized %d %dx%d\n", ev.window.event, ev.window.data1, ev.window.data2);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) return -1;

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("",0, 0,640, 480,0);      
    if (!window) return -1;

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    if (!renderer) return -1;

    flush_event_queue();

    SDL_SetWindowSize(window, 600, 100);
    printf("SetWindowSize\n");

    flush_event_queue();

    int w, h; SDL_GetWindowSize (window, &w, &h);
    printf("%dx%d\n", w, h);
    assert (w == 600);
    assert (h == 100);

    //Now let's draw something and see if it shows up. No--
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_Rect rect1 = {0, 0, 100, 100};
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect1);
    SDL_RenderPresent (renderer);

    SDL_Event sdlEvent; //Wait for key hit, so we can see rect
    do
        SDL_WaitEvent (&sdlEvent);
    while (sdlEvent.type != SDL_KEYDOWN);


    return 0;
}
```

The resulting output is

```
ev.type=4352
ev.type=4352
ev.type=512
window event 1
ev.type=512
window event 2
ev.type=512
window event 1
ev.type=512
window event 4
ev.type=512
window event 3
ev.type=512
window event 12
ev.type=512
window event 15
ev.type=770
SetWindowSize
ev.type=512
window event 6
resized 6 600x100
600x100
```

If I comment out that first `flush_event_queue()` call in the new test, I don't ever get to the output -- it crashes on my `assert`s.

Comment: Can't reproduce. What's your OS, window system and window manager? What values do you get?

Comment: Unix is not a single OS, and linux is not really unix but rather unix-like. Is your graphics system based on wayland or X11? Does window size actually change or window manager rejects change and resizes it back?

Comment: Ok I can reproduce it in virtual machine with latest ubuntu and gnome. While I haven't diagnosed issue yet as a workaround I'd recommend flushing event queue _before_ changing window size.

Comment: I did SDL_FlushEvents(SDL_FIRSTEVENT, SDL_LASTEVENT); before and after changing window size, but no help yet. I appreciate all that you are doing!

Comment: Sorry, by flushing I meant `while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev)){}` or something like that (and &ev can't be NULL). `SDL_FlushEvent` only clears currently accumulated events, here we're interested in event that is not yet fetched from window system (I suspect resize from window creation not received yet, and after second resize you get that event and SDL believes that window system resized your window back).

Comment: OK, got it. No resolution yet.

Comment: Can you add output of [this test](https://pastebin.com/f4bdMG4t) to question, as well as the same thing with first flush commented out?

Comment: That first `flush_event_queue` does make `SSDL_GetWindowSize` return the right values! It also makes things stop showing up on the screen. Actually, they do show up, but in the wrong place: I resized the window to 600x300, and saw the rectangle which should go at 0,0, looking like it might have been at 0, 300. So it fixed one thing and broke another -- IDK why!

Comment: IDK if I should split this into two questions. I will if the community thinks I should.

Comment: @TopologicalSort Would be better if you do I think.

Comment: keltar, if you'll post your fix as an answer, I'll accept that. I've posted the drawing offset problem as a new question per suggestion, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57193038/after-sdl-setwindowsize-resizes-drawing-is-done-offset-down-the-screen .